# Java package path same as class path in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, class, package, conflict

I have a package com.a.b which has classes com.a.b.a, com.a.b.b, com.a.b.c
I also have a class in the package com.a called b (so it's path is com.a.b too)

My class only depends on the classes in the package com.a.b, but THEY depend on the CLASS com.a.b. I can compile this fine using javac as it does not care about the dependencies of my dependencies.
However, eclipse does not let me compile giving me "The type com.a.b cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from the required .class files". Javac lets me compile fine without caring about that though (it's just more hassle), so why doesn't eclipse?

Edit: I should mention I have removed com.a.b from the build path because eclipse does not let me access com.a.b.a/b/c otherwise (it resolves com.a.b to a class instead of a package). This is why eclipse cannot resolve com.a.b, the thing is, it shouldn't have to in order to build because I am not using it until run time.

Comment: Have you tried doing a `refresh` and `clean` on your project? It sounds like things should compile in Eclipse just fine.

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I've spammed F5 abunch of times and cleaned the workspace and still get the same error. The error makes sense though and is referring directly to what I am doing so surely it's some feature of eclipse? I've also tried disabling the 'forbidden reference' error but it does not help.

Comment: Is the class an external dependency? perhaps in a jar? Have you added the jar to your classpath? (Right click on project in Package Explorer > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries Tab > Add JARS... Button)